# Как удалить из git ветку вместе с remote tracking?

Tags: git-branch

Довольно часто использую вместе такие команды

```
git branch -D branch_name
git branch -rd origin/branch_name
```

То есть удалить ветку, и удалить её tracking версию.

Можно ли сделать и то и другое вместе более коротким запросом?

p.s. Поясню контекст. Я забираю к себе чью-то ветку на код ревью. После просмотра нужно удалить, чтобы не замусоривать свой локальный репозиторий чужими ветками.